# Falha acentuação XML para mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Estou enfrentando um erro estranho com acentuação.
Defini meu banco, tabela e estrutura para UTF-8.
Utilizo:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

E mesmo assim, quando faço o upload do arquivo XML, salva no banco com erro de formatação. Já utilizei `"accept-charset"` no FORM, e também salva com erros na acentuação.

Achei que fosse o arquivo do XML que estava com os erros, porém abri ele pelo "notepad++" (que também já está como UTF-8 sem BOM), e a falha persiste.

Alguém já passou por este problema?

Comment: Consegue usar um debugg no servidor e verificar se o xml que você fez upload contém erros de acentuação? pois assim isola o problema, sendo ele na inserção no banco (desculpe se estiver sendo redundante).

Comment: Verifiquei aqui, e o XML está sem erros de acentuação.
É provável que ocorra esta falha no momento que é feito o upload. Agora, como isso ocorre, eu não sei.
Quando salva, já fica com a formatação sem acentuação.
ex: SÃ£o Paulo

Comment: Pelo que eu vi no seu código vc está definindo no php que toda consulta deve ser feita no padrão utf-8, você se certificou no seu banco de dados e suas tabelas estão nesse mesmo padrão de collection?

Comment: Opa, tudo bem @RafaelAndrade?

Comment: Opa, tudo bem @RafaelAndrade?
Então, descobri onde está a falha, e ainda não sei como resolver, mas estou usando um método "paliativo". Aparentemente, o arquivo que salvo pelo EXCEL, formata para UTF-8, salva com acentuação tanto no XML quanto em CSV (sim criei outro script para enviar CSV).
Porém, sempre que faço upload, fica tudo sem formatação no banco.
Então, ao invés de abrir com o notepad++ para ver o arquivo, abri com o notepad do windows e salvei como "nome.xml (ou csv)", e funcionou.
Não sei porque funcionou hahaha, mas estou usando assim por enquanto.